# Is there a way to separate the design window in dreamweaver and put in on my second screen?

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there a way to separate the design window in Dreamweaver and put in on my second screen.
So then i can have the code view on my main screen and design view on the second screen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just expand the window into both screens. To do this you need to restore the window down, grab the corner of the window, and expand to the second screen. That's what I do with it so that my Code View is on my left monitor and Live View is on my right.